# cakePHP accessing table without model

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks

I have to modify an existing project, coded in cakephp. I am not much aware of cakephp.
I need to access tables in database, without using model. The existing code is as below:

There are two tables  'users' and 'videos'. In one of the controller following code is used to access table.

```
public $uses = array('User','Video');

$data = $this->User->findByPhone($phone);
```

My doubt is how does the control identify 'User' as an object pointed to 'users' table ? 
Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing a controller to access additional models through the $uses variable.

Model classes represent data and are used in CakePHP applications for data access. They generally represent a database table.

If model class is not defined then it uses AppModel  and AppModel extend libray model class that describes :-

model classes represent data and are used in CakePHP applications for data access. They generally represent a database table but can be used to access anything that manipulates data such as files, external web services, or iCal events.

Comment: Thank you. In case, if I have a table called 'photos', Can I access it like this:
-------
$this->Photo->set();  ------

Comment: yes you can but you need to set 'Photo' in $uses as its in your code sample.

Comment: Thank you. So that will work correct. My doubt was how is the system identifying 'Photo' as a pointer for 'photos' table, when there are many other tables.

Comment: @BrianChristo you can add as many as you want in `$uses` variable.Read some cakephp conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Cake is all about [conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable).
You can change models table using [useTable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable)